# How can apply the templateBinding on image button in silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new on using Sliverlight.  Hope someone can help me.   I need the image buttons to show the order is  on the complete or process status. The click event functions of these two are same to navigate the same page. Currently I created two customer Image Button on App.xaml  because the Source of this image cannot do “TemplateBinding”  ; the button doesn’t has this property.   Is it a better way to do it?

There is my code:

```
<Style x:Key="btnComplete" TargetType="Button"  >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image  Height="50" Width="120" Stretch="none"   Source="../images/btnComplete.png"/>                            
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achive this is to create a transparent controltemplate for the button and add image as content to the button anywhere you want.

The button code in your page will be like below.

```
   <Button  Height="100" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButtonStyle}" Click="TwitterBtn_Click">
         <Image Height="100" Source="YourIcon.png" Width="100"/>
   </Button>
```

And the TransparentButtonStyle can be declared in App.xaml . Thats all!

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
               <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```